# Show that the function $f(x)=x^3, (x \in \Bbb{R} )$ is not uniformly continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, uniform-continuity

I have been assigned this question but the solution given uses a different method so i don't know if my solution is correct

$$\exists \bar{\epsilon} \gt0 \quad \text{s.t.} \quad|\bar{x}-\bar{y}|\lt\delta $$
$$\exists \bar{x},\bar{y} \in D \quad \text{s.t.} \quad |f(\bar{x})-f(\bar{y})|\geq\epsilon$$
$$\forall \delta \gt0 \leftrightsquigarrow \forall n\in\Bbb{N} $$
$$\forall \delta \gt0 \; \exists n\in\Bbb{N} \quad \text{s.t.} \quad \frac1n \lt \delta$$
$$|\bar{x}-\bar{y}| \lt \frac1n \lt \delta$$
$$\bar{x} = \bar{x}_n \quad \bar{y} = \bar{y}_n$$
$$|\bar{x}_n-\bar{y}_n| \lt \frac1n \quad \bar{y}_n=\bar{x}_n-\frac1{2n}$$
$$|\bar{x}_n-\bar{y}_n|=|\bar{x}_n-\bar{x}_n+\frac1{2n}|=\frac1{2n} \lt \frac1n$$
$$\bar{y}_n=\bar{x}_n-\frac1{2n}$$
$$|\bar{x}_n-\bar{y}_n|=\frac1{2n} \lt \frac1n$$
$$\text{choose $\bar{\epsilon}=1$} $$
$$|f(\bar{x})-f(\bar{y})| \geq \bar{\epsilon}=1$$
$$|\bar{x}_n^3 - (\bar{x}_n^3 - \frac{3\bar{x}_n^2}{2n} + \frac{3\bar{x}_n}{4n^2} - \frac1{8n^3})|$$
$$=|\frac{3\bar{x}_n^2}{2n} - \frac{3\bar{x}_n}{4n^2} + \frac1{8n^3}| $$
$$\text{choose $\bar{x}_n=2n^2$}$$
$$=|\frac{3(2n^2)^2}{2n} - \frac{3(2n^2)}{4n^2} + \frac1{8n^3}|$$
$$=|6n^3-\frac32+\frac1{8n^3}|\geq1$$
$$\text{thus $f(x)=x^3, (x \in \Bbb{R} )$ is not uniformly continuous, as required}$$

Comment: I think it would be more readable if you explain what your symbols mean.

Answer (score 1):

This is a standard proof.

Let us fix
$$
\epsilon = 1
$$

Given any $\delta > 0$, we choose a real number $x > 0$ such that
$$
{3 \delta x^2 \over 2} > 1
$$

Obviously,
$$
\left| (x + {\delta \over 2}) - x \right| = {\delta \over 2} < \delta
$$

However, we have
$$
 \left| \left( x + {\delta \over 2} \right)^3 - x^3 \right| =
\left|  {3 \delta x^2 \over 2} +
{3 \delta^2 x \over 2^2} + {\delta^3 \over 2^3} \right| \geq {3 \delta x^2 \over 2} > 1
$$

Thus, we have shown that
$$
f(x) = x^3
$$
is not uniformly continuous on $\mathbf{R}$.